# in pysimplegui, simplifying event loop by calling an event handler function

Tags: python, event-handling, pysimplegui

I wanted to simplify the event loop by providing a function to call when the element would generate an event. This works because the 'key' of the elements can also be an object, in this case a newly created Event object.
I provide an event handler function to be called, and the idea was that this was called with the value returned by the win.read().

This is my simple example:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

class Event:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.handler = func

def inputHandler(value):
    print (f"received {value}") 

def buttonHandler(button):
    print ('button was pressed')

def checkBoxHandler(checkbox):
    print (f'check was set {checkbox}')


input = sg.Input('Hello', enable_events = True, readonly=False, key = Event(inputHandler))
check = sg.Checkbox('check this', enable_events = True, key = Event(checkBoxHandler))
button = sg.Button('a button', key = Event(buttonHandler))

# note: elements above can also simply be inserted in layout below

layout = [
    [input],
    [check],
    [button],
]

win = sg.Window('testing function calls as events', layout)

while (True):
    event, values = win.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED: 
        break

    event.handler(values[event])

win.close()
```

This works as expected for the input and the checkbox.
When pressing the button it bombs out with a KeyError on the values[].

I guess the button is not present in values[...] so a simple

```
if event in values:
    ...
```

might work (did not test)

But:

1. would anybody think of something to make it universal?
2. unrelated to the event loop, why would the values[buttonkey] not contain the pressed/released state?

Comment: Buttons, like Text, Images, etc, don't have an "input" part to them for the most part so they're not in the values dictionary.  Not all elements with keys have an entry in the values dictionary (as you've discovered).

Comment: Understandably no input part as these elements are passive (Text, Images, but similarly Frames, and more). They do not deliver events either (I least I believe so). Buttons do, and their Input is that they are pressed.

Comment: Generating an event isn't what determines goes in the dictionary.  Image & Test elements both can create events.  It was an architectural design decision.  Lots of directions it could have gone.  I was explaining how it works.  You're welcome to open an Enhancement on the PSG GitHub with your suggestions.

Comment: Oh, I believe you guys are more creative and capable then me. The simple in the name pysimpleGUI does imply that choices were made to make it so. I like it a lot. 
The reason I looked into this was because my initially simple project was slowly getting a huge event handling loop with an large number of 
    if event == whatever:
running at every event. I was searching for an easy way to prepare statements in such a way to not have to search the event, but to call directly the correct function.

Comment: The [Demo Program Dispatchers](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Dispatchers.py) may be of interest. It shows several implementations dispatchers.